# Where can I find Flutter layout inspector in Visual Code Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-layout

I mean this one:
[image]

I can see this:
[image]

As far as I remember Visual Code used to have it too even though it was accessible as a Chrome tab instead of a Visual Studio Code tab.

Currently I only see the widget tree, I'm sure there is a inspector for memory, performance...

Answer (score 1):

Practically there is no such Layout inspector in VSCode.

What you can do is as follows:

1. Run your app on the physical device or on the emulator.
2. Press `Ctrl + Alt + D` on windows OS.
3. Your Profiler will run on WEB

In simple words what you have shown in the first image is what is possible in VSCode.
In Android Studio you have it located at the bottom(the status bar)

Answer (score 1):

Version: 1.50.1

You should be able to view it in
`Dart: Open DevTools` section[image]

Comment: Thanks. Are you on Windows or on macOS? I have a macOS 1.50.1 and I see the same thing that you got EXCEPT for the Layout Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that currently for web only the widget inspector & debugger are available, see [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60342).

If like me you agree that a message to inform the dev why these are not available instead of being mysteriously missing, upvote the GitHub issue.